# Why MovieClip is not visible?

Tags: haxe, createjs

I tried to use createjs to create a movieClip and add an image inside it like this:

```
rect2 = new Bitmap(_preloader.getResult("rect").result);
mv = new MovieClip("single", 0, false, []);
mv.addChild(rect2);
_stage.addChild(mv);
```

I expect to see `rect2` on stage, but it dose not show up, if I added `rect2` to stage it will show up, so what's I am missing here?

Comment: What platform are you targeting ? How are you compiling it ? How is that related with createjs ?

Comment: I am targeting HTML5, compiling it using haxe nme, createjs is a library that has as3 apis to create graphics and interactivity, can't you see that I am using it in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using MovieClip? It is mainly used to handle export from Flash Pro using Toolkit for CreateJS.

Instead, you might try using a Bitmap instance, which wraps an image, canvas, or video element.

One note for MovieClips is that you need to gotoAndStop/gotoAndPlay in order to set the initial state, it does not "default" to the first frame like Flash.